# How to get value of input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, web-frontend

How to get value of input tag onclick image and all value of input tag is different?

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="1" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src='images/heart.png' id='wishlistRent1' class='wishlist_icon>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="2" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src='images/heart.png' id='wishlistRent1' class='wishlist_icon>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="3" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src='images/heart.png' id='wishlistRent1' class='wishlist_icon>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="4" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src='images/heart.png' id='wishlistRent1' class='wishlist_icon>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.
You have multiple markup mistakes. Each ID needs to be unique (wishlistRent1 and getHeart need to be different for each element). You style tag is incomplete and your class name wishlist_icon needs an extra quote to close out the statement. When all that is fixed, check jQuery's .prev() function. Then post the code you tried and we'll help you.

Comment: So bind events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers that I have seen so far, assume that you want to use jQuery. If you would like to use Vanilla JavaScript, you can do it like this:

```
var heartImage = document.getElementById( 'wishlistRent1' );

heartImage.onclick = function() {
  console.log( 'Value: ', document.getElementById('getHeart1').value );
};
```

Also:

- Make sure your classes in your HTML end with a quote. Not closing
  these causes issues. Example: **class='wishlist_icon** needs to be **class='wishlist_icon'**
- Make sure you use a different id for each HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't use and Id more than once. You are using the Id "getHeart" four times. 
Second, to get the value of a specific field, you could do something like:

```
$("#idOfYourElement").click(function(){
        return this.value;
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below , use `onClick` event and `onClick` of any `image` find `input` value of that particular image :

```js
$("img").click(function(){
       console.log($(this).parent().find('input').val());
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="1" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src="images/heart.png" id="wishlistRent1" class="wishlist_icon">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="2" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src="images/heart.png" id=
"wishlistRent1" class="wishlist_icon">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="3" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src="images/heart.png" id="wishlistRent1" class="wishlist_icon">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" value="4" style="display:" id="getHeart">
  <img src="images/heart.png" id="wishlistRent1" class="wishlist_icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you fix your html script for closing comma after class tag:

(example) `class='wishlist_icon>` to `class='wishlist_icon'>`, you can do the following to check your values:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedInput = '';
    $('img').click(function() {
        selectedInput = $(this).parent().find('input');
        alert('Value of selected input = ' + selectedInput.val());
    });
});
```

Similarly `selectedInput.attr('yourInputBoxPropertyHere')` can be used to get the corresponding value, eg: `selectedInput.attr('id')` would give you the id.